# How to SELECT Frequently asked questions from MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is possible to get "FAQ" from MySQL database.I have table where I store questions and answers.Everyday on my site we get thousands questions.

Now I'm count,in my database I have 142,283 questions.
My idea is reduce it number with creating FAQ.But is there any way to get faq with select.

I understand that questions are not 100% same,but any way which will count number of most popular words/sentence.

**Table structure:**

```
ID
question
answer
staff
```

Thanks
(Sorry for my English)

Comment: You will need more than just SQL to do this. If you want to just get the questions from a table you could go with a simple `SELECT` query, but if you also want to count the most popular questions or something like that you would need a new column for that

Comment: you can create a query that will match single or multiple words from given input question using LIKE in where clause from your existing question .........but keep in mind that LIKE may increase query cost .......so do the properly indexing ...Best of luck

Comment: You could let the users sort it out: let the user answer questions, give them reputation and little shiny badges for doing so, and give them a way to mark questions as duplicates (maybe call those buttons e.g. "close" or "flag"; you can extend that to allow the user to identify e.g. spam). Bonus points if you allow the user to be able to up- and downvote questions and answers and use this to order your search results. Double bonus points if you allow users to edit other user's questions/answers (and/or delete duplicates/spam) and let different users decide if those edits are good or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by on your question column. 
Also you can use LIKE operator for the most common used words like "What, why, where, how, etc.".